# Getting child to fill parent height in menu

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to get the child(LI) to fill the parent(UL) in my main menu here website-test-lab.com/sites/mirandaparsons/

I am using parts of flexbox to make the menu vertically and horizontally centered but you will notice that I need the white borders to be full height of the menu.

I've seen a lot of 'hacks' to get this to work but surely there is an easier way? Perhaps with flexbox or even a JS snippet?

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

- Give the *ul*: **height**: *60px*;
- Remover margins from *li*
- Give *li a*: **padding**: *20px 0.5em*;

**Result:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYdPc.png

Comment: The site and menu are responsive so giving a pixel set height will break things. Especially if new menu links are added. Thanks